# using random pics with Twython

Tags: python, bots, twython

I'm using Twython to make a bot who post random image from a folder, here is the code !

```
from twython import Twython
import glob
import random

app_key = "XXX"
app_secret = "XXX"
oauth_token = "XXX" 
oauth_token_secret = "XXX"
twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

def RandomImageTwitt(folder):
        #Takes the folder where your images are as input
        images = glob.glob(folder + "*")
        image_open = open(images[random.randint(0,len(images))-1])
        #Tweeting
        image_ids = twitter.upload_media(media=image_open)
        twitter.update_status(status='hello this is a status', media_ids=image_ids['media_id'])

 RandomImageTwitt("/home/Pi/Bots/Pictures/")
```

Ok, and when i use python script.py, it return this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 20, in <module>
  RandomImageTwitt("/home/Pi/Bots/Pictures/")
File "script.py", line 14, in RandomImageTwitt
  image_open = open(images[random.randint(0,len(images))-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm beginner in Python, if that can help, all my files are stored like this : 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg... every files are in jpg and the list begin from 1.

Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you use `random.choice`? `images[random.randint(0, len(images))-1]` → `random.choice(images)` which will prevent this kind of index mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, so, I replaced `image_open = open(images[random.randint(0,len(images))-1])` with `image_open = random.choice(images)`, i modifyied nothing else, and i'm getting this error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ewhring.py", line 20, in <module>
    RandomImageTwitt("/home/Pi/Bots/Pictures/")
  File "ewhring.py", line 14, in RandomImageTwitt
    image_open = random.choice(images)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 275, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: What do you get if you print `images`? Is it empty?

Comment: I used `print (images)` just returning the error not my print..

Comment: How about `print(len(images))`?

Comment: Just the error, if this can help, I added the print at the end of my code, i don't know if this impact something

Comment: Add `print(images)` after the line `images = glob.glob(folder + "*")`.

Comment: Nice ! Empty array. x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `images` is not empty.

BTW, it's better to use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) (no need to calculate index yourself, easier to read):

```
image_open = open(random.choice(images))
```

`random.choice` will also raise `IndexError` if the sequence is empty.

Comment: Thanks dude, but why the sequence is empty ?

Comment: Oh sh*t, it was just /home/pi/Bots/Pictures/ and not /home/Pi/Bots/Pictures.  So thanks for the random.choice and have a nice day bro !